# How download a dataframe with R syntax in Google Colab?

Tags: r, csv, google-colaboratory

I am using the R syntax in Google Colab. I have a dataframe that I want to download to a csv file. This is how I am using R in Google Colab `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can export a dataframe to a csv by executing

```
write.csv(df,"filename.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The execution of this command will result in the creation of the csv file named `filename.csv` in your colab environment.

I hope I answered your question, provide more details for further help.